# Unable to stream pdf when put css in document to print

Tags: css, character-encoding, inline, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF the lastest version `DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3`. The problem is I can't put any css code onto the document. Everytime I tried it will says `Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent`. No matter I tried to remove any whitespace nor un-line break.

This is not work:

```
h1{
border:solid 3px red;
color:red;   
}
```

But this one work:

```
<h1 style="border:solid 3px red;color:red;">Copy Only</h1>
```

And I also cannot add a charset into a document as well.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Because the charset is not work. My document is unreadable - it's not only English, some lang else.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

"Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent" indicates that some content was sent to the browser before dompdf was able to send the PDF. Based on previous experience, PHP is probably inserting a warning into the content stream. If you render without streaming the PDF you can see the warning and address the issue. Or open the PDF in a text editor; the warnings will be at the top of the file.

Also, you likely have the display_errors php.ini setting set to 1/true and also are using output buffering. Generally we recommended that you disable sending errors to the browser and/or disable output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried changing everything in the script to get rid of the white spaces. But not work. Now I removed everything before php code, then works. Internal css has removed and use it as an inline instead.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my encoding issues - use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

(See https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo)